# R Studio: ~ as “unexpected input” in plot()

Tags: r, plot

I have been using R studio for a while and just got around to linear regression. To start, I wanted to plot my data, but my R Studio keeps on giving me an error for my use of the ~ symbol.

Here is the code:

```
STR <- c(15, 17, 19, 20, 22)

TestScore <- c(680, 640, 670, 660, 630)

plot(TestScore ~ STR)
```

The console then tells me:

> ‘Error : unexpected input in “plot(TestScore ?”

I have installed library(AER) and library(MASS) which seem to be the only other preconditions for this to work.

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you copy/paste the code from this page do you get the error? The unexpected input makes me think you may have copied the code from something like a PDF which inserted some kind of extra whitespace character or other un-printable character into your code. Try re-typing it from scratch rather than copy/pasting to see if it goes away. I don't have any problems running to code you provided.

Answer (score -1):

Might be a problem to do with the locale. Try this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE.UTF-8")
```

The German locale is just an example. Check out `?Sys.setlocale` for a locale appropriate to you.

Comment: You recommend just changing to a German locale? Seems like an odd suggestion. What exactly do you think the problem is?

Comment: Can you share why you think the locale is part of the problem? Is there a locale where tildes don't work?

Comment: I suggest we let the OP find out whether the locale is part of the problem. My experience has been that the locale is key in whether or not characters are displayed and recognized in the right way.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue and, if so, how?

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine here, but if you're doing linear modelling you really want to put into one data frame.

Try this, but as per previous comments start a new script and either copy from here or type it new:

```
STR <- c(15, 17, 19, 20, 22)
TestScore <- c(680, 640, 670, 660, 630)
plot(TestScore ~ STR)

your.data = data.frame(STR, TestScore)
glimpse(your.data)

your.model <- lm(data = your.data, TestScore ~ STR)

anova(your.model)
summary(your.model)
```

Comment: This adds no new insight on the OP's problem: the fact that the simple use of the tilde produced an error.

Comment: True. Apologies, I was trying to be helpful and prevent a problem the OP would have once they got to doing the linear regression they said they were aiming towards before having this problem.